# Java 8: How can I check if all the fields of an object are NULL except from one

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to check if all the fields of an instantiated class are all NULL EXCEPT FROM the id.

For example:

```
class Doggy {
   String id;
   String name;
   String breed;
   String eyeColour;
   String hairColour;
   Integer age;
   Long height;
   Long weight;
   //getters & setters
}
```

I would like to know if it can happen using java 8.
Thank you in advance.

I have an instantiated object like this:

```
Doggy doggy = new Doggy;
doggy.setId("123");
```

I would like a more elegant way to do the following:

```
if (doggy.getId()!=null && doggy.getName()==null && doggy.getBreed()==null && 
        doggy.getEyeColour()==null && doggy.getHairColour()==null && 
        doggy.getAge()==null && doggy.getHeight()==null && doggy.getWeight()==null) {
   doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Try using null equality on your fields? It's hard to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: OK, I corrected it!

Comment: I want something like this but this checks all the fields. `if (Stream.of(doggy).allMatch(Objects::isNull)) {doSomething;}`

Comment: you could use reflection to turn your parameters into a Map of key/value, or just List of values if you don't care about the field names. then use something like your code snippet to check for a null. worth searching for answers on that.

Comment: There does not exist a more elegant way.  At best, you can add a method to the Doggy class which does the check, like `public boolean hasIdButNoData()`.

Answer (score 6):

If by java 8 here we mean using streams you can do

```java
Doggy doggy = new Doggy();
doggy.id = "1";
boolean allIsNullButId = Arrays.stream(Doggy.class.getDeclaredFields()).allMatch(f -> {
    try {
        return (f.getName().equals("id") && f.get(doggy) != null) || f.get(doggy) == null;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice approach, but `getFields()` should be `getDeclaredFields()` to include non-public fields. In OP's `Doggy` class, `getFields()` would yield an empty array if I'm not mistaken, since her fields are currently class-private (and usually you'd have private fields with public getters/setters). Apart from that it seems to work: [Verify getFields() vs getDeclaredFields()](https://ideone.com/maDXED).

Answer (score 1):

You can make mandatory all the fields that you need within the constructor.
Here two examples using the ***Lombok*** library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.10):

For mandatory parameters at the instantiation, like new Doggy("mandatoryName", 1, etc..);

```
@Data
public class Doggy {
    private Integer id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private Integer age;
}
```

If you can't instantiate the object with all the parameters, this example allows to create the object like this: new Doggy(); but you need to be sure that you are calling all the Doggy setters for every mandatory parameter. (See the docs for more information: https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull)

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor // Here is the difference
public class Doggy {
    private Integer id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private BigDecimal amount;
}

//
final Doggy doggy = new Doggy();
...
doggy.setName(null);

// doggy.setName(null) is firing this generated code by Lombok:
public void setName(@NonNull final String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("name is marked non-null but is null");
        } else {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

A more standard solution is using ***javax.valid***, here is a full example: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/javaxval

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do it in Java 8 with streams, then you can simply filter a `List<Doggy>` for those instances that are not initialized as desired:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Doggy> doggies = new ArrayList<>();
    doggies.add(new Doggy(null, "Cujo", "Bernard", "blue-green", "white-brown",
            Integer.valueOf(3), Long.valueOf(14), Long.valueOf(11)));
    doggies.add(new Doggy(null, "Lassie", "Collie", "blue", "brown",
            Integer.valueOf(8), Long.valueOf(9), null));
    doggies.add(new Doggy("ID", "Wolfy", "Husky", "icy-blue", "gray-white",
            Integer.valueOf(5), Long.valueOf(11), Long.valueOf(10)));
    doggies.add(new Doggy(null, "Rex", null, "blue", "brown",
            Integer.valueOf(9), Long.valueOf(10), Long.valueOf(10)));

    // "simply" filter and check all the fields if they are null
    List<Doggy> doggiesNotInitializedAsDesired = doggies.stream()
            .filter(doggy -> doggy.getName() == null || doggy.getBreed() == null 
                    || doggy.getEyeColour() == null || doggy.getHairColour() == null 
                    || doggy.getAge() == null || doggy.getHeight() == null
                    || doggy.getWeight() == null 
                    || doggy.getId() != null) // check == null for the special case ID
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    doggiesNotInitializedAsDesired.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The result is a `List<Doggy>` containing those who have at least one field initialized with `null` except from the `id` or have an `id` that is not `null`:

```
Doggy [id=null, name=Lassie, breed=Collie, eyeColour=blue, hairColour=brown, age=8, height=9, weight=null]
Doggy [id=ID, name=Wolfy, breed=Husky, eyeColour=icy-blue, hairColour=gray-white, age=5, height=11, weight=10]
Doggy [id=null, name=Rex, breed=null, eyeColour=blue, hairColour=brown, age=9, height=10, weight=10]
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a method like:

```
public void checkFields(Doggy obj) throws DoggyNULLException
{
if (obj.getName().isBlank())
 throw new DoggyNULLException();
}
```

do it for every field
isBlank() is the method that you use for null obj.

Comment: I meant that she should do it for every propriety that she needs to use it. As someone said earlier, primitives can't be null.

Comment: what about `Integer`? and why not simply ask if property is not equal to null? `isBlank()` is not what you use to check for null.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29

Ok, I guess isBlank it's what she needs for strings. Otherwise, it's just my opinion. Peace!

Comment: please check your code again. it does not call apache commons at all